# rails.cache doesn't contain my cached datas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

as [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) link says, rails default cache store implemention is file store and this configuration can be changed from `config/environments/development.rb`. **question1**: how can i access these caches through rails console? (`Rails.cache` is used for memory store and not for file store as the guide says).

i changed the cache store to memory store and used cache_action in one of my controllers:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store (in development.rb)

caches_action :my_action (in foocontroller.rb)
```

as the guide says, i can access to them by `Rails.cache` but it contains nothing. why?

Comment: `memory_store` is per process. If you want a shared store you should use either `file_store` or `mem_cache_store`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that memory cache stays in the process so you can't access the cache from the rails console if it was cached on the server because it's 2 different processes